# How to push into the second dimension of a two dimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets, typeerror

I have a list of players in denoted as

```
activeRange[x]
```

where x will vary from day-to-day.

Each of the x values will have to have AT LEAST 4 more subsequent values (likely a bit more). Ideally I'd like the array to look like:

```
activeRange[x][y]
```

So here's what I've done so far:

```
var MATCH = AllData[TotalRows][TotalColumns+1];
activeRange[TotNumPlayers].push(MATCH);
```

This is all located within 3 nested for loops.

```
TotNumPlayers
```

will iterate through a given set declared at the beginning (somewhat like 23). Once done, the

```
TotalRows
```

will iterate, then finally

```
TotalColumns
```

I'm running into the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function push in object mitch
```

mitch is the value of activeRange[0]. I've been staring at this way too long, so any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT: Code inserted below:**
PLEASE IGNORE ALL THE COMMENTS. I COPY/PASTED THIS FROM A BIT OF CODE I USED YESTERDAY TO PERFORM A DIFFERENT FUNCTION. 
**This is the second time I've ever posted on this website, so trying to format this monster to be pretty was scary sounding. Hopefully this is good enough.**

This is how activeRange was declared and initialized.

```
var activeRange = new Array();
for (var b=0; b<=lastRow-2; b++){
    activeRange[b] = sheetRANK.getRange(b+2,1).getValue();
}
```

This is the function.

```
function getTotalScore(activeRange, w) {
    Logger.clear()
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetWAR = ss.getSheetByName('WAR');
    var sheetRANK = ss.getSheetByName('RANK');

    var AllData = sheetRANK.getDataRange().getValues();
    Logger.log('First');
    for (var TotNumPlayers = 0; TotNumPlayers <= activeRange.length; TotNumPlayers++) {
        Logger.log('Second');
        var f = 0;
        for (var TotalColumns = 0; TotalColumns <= AllData[0].length; ++TotalColumns) { // Init n. If n <= the total columns (second dimension), inc n.
            Logger.log('Third');
            for (var TotalRows = 0; TotalRows <= AllData.length; ++TotalRows) { // Init i. If i <= the total rows (first dimension), inc i.
                Logger.log('Fourth');
                //try{ // to avoid errors.
                if (activeRange[TotNumPlayers] != "") {
                    Logger.log('Here?');
                    if (AllData[TotalRows][TotalColumns].valueOf().toUpperCase() == activeRange[TotNumPlayers].toUpperCase()) {
                        Logger.log('How About Here?');
                        var MATCH = AllData[TotalRows][TotalColumns + 1];
                        activeRange.push(TotNumPlayers, MATCH);
                        for (var Calc = 0; Calc <= activeRange[TotNumPlayers].length - 1; Calc++) {
                            var OverallScore = ((activeRange[TotNumPlayers][0] * 1.0) + (activeRange[TotNumPlayers][1] * .75) + (activeRange[TotNumPlayers][2] * .50) + (activeRange[TotNumPlayers][3] * .25));
                            sheetRANK.getRange(activeRange[TotNumPlayers] + 1, 2).setValue(OverallScore);

                            f = f + 1;
                        }
                        if (TotalRows == AllData.length - 1 && TotalColumns == AllData[0].length - 1 && f == 0) {
                            Browser.msgBox('No names matching \'' + activeRange[TotNumPlayers] + '\' found. Check your spelling!');
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so just to clarify, `activeRange` is a list of players and `activeRange[x]` yields an object?

Comment: An example of what's in the activerange array would help.  The error is telling us that you can't push into an object named 'mitch' because its not an array.  The object structure would help clarify

Comment: Post the array structure of `activeRange`, please!

Comment: @Anchor All values within activeRange[x] are strings. Example: `activeRange[0] = mitch`, `activeRange[1] = Viper`, and so on and so on. I used a for loop along with getRange().getValue() to produce the array.

Comment: you're attempting to call `push` on a string, which is why you are getting an error

Comment: @Buzinas I apologize, I'm quite new at this (and JavaScript in general), are you asking the data types contained within the array activeRange[]? If so, they are all strings. I want each string in activeRange to also have a second part (containing all integer data. For example: `activeRange[0]` would be mitch. Suppose mitch had 4 different data that I wanted associated with him. Suppose `data1 = 10` `data2 = 11` `data3 = 12` `data4 = 13`. Now, I would want `activeRange[0][0]` to be 10, `activeRange[0][1]` to be 11 and so on.

Comment: @Anchor So how would I accomplish this? It seems so obvious now, but I couldn't wrap my mind around why it wasn't working... Is it possible?

Comment: @Anchor could I perhaps do something like `activeRange.push(TotNumPlayers,MATCH);`? Would that work?

Comment: @user5349418 can you post the code you've tried so far to get that error?

Comment: you are consufing many languajes here.. use an object {} not array  activeRange = { "name": MyAray};

Comment: @Buzinas Updated main post.

Comment: @QuijoteShin This is my first project ever with JavaScript, so I've been using several online resources to make this project happen, so I apologize for the mismatch. I'm still very new at JavaScript.

Comment: its ok, keep in mind that js don't naturally support associative arrays, try to use objects instead  for that purpose http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try thinking about what kind of data structures you can use to make your life easier. For this particular case, you have a list of players that you want to associate some data with. You'd probably use a structure like:

```
activeRange = [
  {
    name: 'mitch',
    data: []
  }
]
```

When you want to update the data, you'd simply call `activeRange[0].data.push(someData)`.

`activeRange` is an array of players and each player is represented by an object with some properties, (name, data, etc). 
Calling `activeRange[0]` yields the first player in your array and `activeRange[0].data` will yield the data associated with that player, which you can then manipulate however you want (`push`, `pop`, etc)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but how do I implement that with what I already have? (I updated the main post to include my current code). I don't even know where to begin...

Comment: it's impossible to say, without knowing what your input data looks like and what your expected output is. To be honest I think you are overcomplicating things in the code you posted and you are only using arrays (objects are very useful too). It might seem like a lot of work, but I would just rewrite the whole thing keeping in mind some of the comments posted here. Do some research about javascript objects first, and be clear about what your input is and what your desired output is. Don't give up!

Comment: I would much prefer to just get this one simple part working because the rest of the code works pretty well. I've done a bit of research on objects since I posted this question, and I'm going to try to make use of them here. I want to point out that literally every other piece of the program functions as expected, I'm just having issues with the mapping of data. I am going to take an array of x amount of names. I want each of those names to have 4 elements to add more data (an array of an array if you will, which is why I tried the 2D array first). **FIRST COMMENT**

Comment: So array[x] will = playername. x is any value between 1 and 50. This part works fine, I can gather the names and put them in the array. What I want to do next is add y elements to each of their names so array[x][y] is what I was thinking. That way say for example x=3='Viper' and y=2='1180', I could take Viper's position on a spreadsheet and take his y value and put it in the column next to him. (Not exactly but it's close enough) **SECOND COMMENT**

Comment: Now I have another question for you. Given that you know that. Given that I would rather do it with objects, I've tried this: `var array = [{data: []}];`, so I should have array[].data[] right? I populated array[] with my list of names. Now when I try `array[number].data.push(VALUE)` I get "Cannot call method push of undefined"

Comment: you're accessing the index of an array item that does not exist. You have to make sure that array[number] actually returns something first

Comment: That's the exact same thing I did wrong earlier... How would I do this? My mind is boggled I can't think of anything! I want to take the location of the value, not the value itself! I want to take the location of Viper and add his values, not 'Viper' himself. I would like to thank you, by the way. You've helped me so much!

Comment: Basically I want to take Viper's location in array and add values to array.data that only work for him. As I said before, basically I want to take the array(location of viper).data.push(some value) and the end result be array[locationofviper].data[0] is Viper's score for War#1, and array[locationofmitch].data[0] is mitch's score for War#1.

Comment: The main concept is that your array needs to be an array of objects first, not strings. Secondly, you need to make sure that the object at the index you are accessing actually exists. That is, `array[i] != undefined`.

Comment: it sounds like you keep trying to associate a player's name with his data when in reality you need to associate a player's *object* with his data... so as above:
`
activeRange = [
  {
    name: 'mitch',
    data: []
  },
  {
  name: 'bob',
  data: []
  },
...
]
`

Comment: does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense, I just don't know how I would populate that list through code iteration. Like I said, I don't know how many players there'll be. There could be 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, or n. (**but I have the list of the names as the first column. I have code that adds names to the list in the first column based on new players**) How would I populate the names? How would I populate the data for each name and how would I reference the data from a single player? I'm so sorry for taking so much of your time, I truly appreciate your help here, though!

Comment: iterate through each row of the first column of your input data, creating a player object for each name on each iteration: for (var i=0; i<playerNames[0].length; i++) { activeRange.push({ name: array[0][i], data: [] }) }

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you need a structure more like this

```
var activeRange = [
    {
      name: 'mitch',
      otherData: [
        10,
        11,
        12, 
        13
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'viper',
      otherData: [
        //values
      ]
    }
]
```

you can access that by `activeRange[0].otherData[2]`

to add to it, just push into the sub array `activeRange[0].otherData.push(newValue)`

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I need! I just don't know how to implement that in my actual code (I'm VERY new at JavaScript, in fact, this is my first project using it!) Thank you for the answer!